# Eclipse 2018-12 module-info.java and build-helper-maven-plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, java-9, m2eclipse

I'm trying to set up module-info.java in my project in Eclipse 2018-12.

Eclipse 2018-12 was complaining:

```
The type com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

so I added

```
requires transitive com.fasterxml.jackson.core;
```

at which point Eclipse said it cannot be resolved to a module, and offered me a quick fix: "move classpath entry to module path".

On doing that, for packages in a source folder added to my build path via:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>add-source</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/pptx4j/java</source>
                        <source>src/xlsx4j/java</source>
                        <source>src/glox4j/java</source>
                        <source>src/diffx</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

and exported in my module-info.java, Eclipse now complains the package does not exist or is empty.

This is so even though the source folders are visible in Build Path > Source.

What to do?  thanks.

Comment: Please show your _Java Build Path_. Are all dependencies on the module path (using JPMS requires not to use the default package, unique module names and a package must only exist in one module only)? Otherwise, JPMS cannot be used and does not make sense. Which error message do you get where after adding `requires transitive com.fasterxml.jackson.core;` (and why do you use `transitive` here)?